# generating visitor overloads using boost preprocessor

Tags: boost, boost-preprocessor

For visiting a variant using a lambda based visitor I came up to the boost.preprocessor for generating the boilerplate required:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>

#define MY_OVERLOAD(r, data, elem) \
    [](elem const& t) { return false; },

#define MY_OVERLOAD_SEQ_MEMBER(typeSeq) \
    BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(MY_OVERLOAD, ~, typeSeq)

#define MY_OVERLOAD_MEMBER(typeSeq) \
    MY_OVERLOAD_SEQ_MEMBER(typeSeq)


int main()
{
    auto visitor = hana::overload(
#if 0   // like to have:
        [](int t) { return false; },
        [](double t) { return false; },
        [](std::string const& t) { false; }
#else
        MY_OVERLOAD_MEMBER((int)(double)(std::string))
#endif
    );
    ...
}
```

This expands as expected so far but failed at last element - there is a trailing comma which fails to compile. I know about BOOST_PP_COMMA_IF, BOOST_PP_ENUM... which do require the number of elements to generate. But this doesn't hold for my use case - the type list is different for each type of visitor of course. Further, I don't be restricted to list the arguments in the manner shown here, a comma separted list as macro argument is also sufficient...

Also note, this code shows only the concept I want to use - in real I don't want to catch POD by reference.

BTW; is the kind of expanding required horizontal or vertically in the term of boost.preprocessor? From feeling horizontal, isn't it?